# sympy symbolic matrix square root

Tags: python, linear-algebra, sympy

Is it possible to use the sympy sqrtm function to compute the square root of a symbolic matrix? For example, if I have the matrix [[1, a], [a, 1]] with a > 0, can I use sympy to compute the square root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sympy import *
a=symbols('a')
m=Matrix( [[1, a], [a, 1]])
m**(1/2)
```

gives

```
Matrix([
[ (-a + 1)**0.5/2 + (a + 1)**0.5/2, -(-a + 1)**0.5/2 + (a + 1)**0.5/2],
[-(-a + 1)**0.5/2 + (a + 1)**0.5/2,  (-a + 1)**0.5/2 + (a + 1)**0.5/2]])
```

To compare result, in Mathematica

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this, and thanks for your patience. We added a new `mat_pow()` function, available in the Github version (v1.1.1.9002). Below I demonstrate a solution prior to this version and also the new function:

```r
library(caracas)

M <- matrix_(c("1", "a", "a", 1), 2, 2)
M
#> [caracas]: ⎡1  a⎤
#>            ⎢    ⎥
#>            ⎣a  1⎦

# Before v1.1.1.9002
eval_to_symbol(paste0(as.character(M), "**(1/2)"))
#> [caracas]: ⎡   _______     _______       _______     _______⎤
#>            ⎢ ╲╱ 1 - a    ╲╱ a + 1      ╲╱ 1 - a    ╲╱ a + 1 ⎥
#>            ⎢ ───────── + ─────────   - ───────── + ─────────⎥
#>            ⎢     2           2             2           2    ⎥
#>            ⎢                                                ⎥
#>            ⎢    _______     _______     _______     _______ ⎥
#>            ⎢  ╲╱ 1 - a    ╲╱ a + 1    ╲╱ 1 - a    ╲╱ a + 1  ⎥
#>            ⎢- ───────── + ─────────   ───────── + ───────── ⎥
#>            ⎣      2           2           2           2     ⎦

# From v1.1.1.9002:
mat_pow(M, 1/2)
#> [caracas]: ⎡   _______     _______       _______     _______⎤
#>            ⎢ ╲╱ 1 - a    ╲╱ a + 1      ╲╱ 1 - a    ╲╱ a + 1 ⎥
#>            ⎢ ───────── + ─────────   - ───────── + ─────────⎥
#>            ⎢     2           2             2           2    ⎥
#>            ⎢                                                ⎥
#>            ⎢    _______     _______     _______     _______ ⎥
#>            ⎢  ╲╱ 1 - a    ╲╱ a + 1    ╲╱ 1 - a    ╲╱ a + 1  ⎥
#>            ⎢- ───────── + ─────────   ───────── + ───────── ⎥
#>            ⎣      2           2           2           2     ⎦
```