# Square root of a SymPy matrix in R using the Caracas package

Tags: r, sympy, linear-algebra

**Language:** `R`; **Package used:** `caracas`

Suppose that I have a complicated symbolic matrix, M and I would like to find the square root of the matrix. That is find A such that `M = A %*% A`. For my problem, `M` is defined below:

```
library(caracas)
# Define M
s_b <- matrix_(c(1, 0, 0, 1), 2, 2)
X <- matrix_(c(2, 1, 1, 1), 2, 2)
o <- symbol('o')
M <- inv(1/o * t(X) %*% X + inv(s_b))
```

I've tried using the `eigenval` and `eigenvec` functions from the `caracas` package to generate a list of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, but cannot figure out how to convert these lists into matrices given that they are of a complicated list of SymPy objects.

The solution in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156257/sympy-symbolic-matrix-square-root) does not help, because rather than taking the square root of the matrix as a a whole R takes the square root of the entries.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out the solution. In this solution I use the diagonalization method.

To assign any symbolic value into a symbolic matrix one must convert it to a character first. ie. one must use the `as.character` function.

The following code generates `P,D` in `R` such that for a sample symbolic matrix `M`, `M=P %*% D %*% inv(P)`

> library(caracas)
>
> a=symbol('a')
>
> m=matrix_( c("1", "a", "a", "1"), 2)
>
> eigenVec_V_b <- eigenvec(m)
>
> D <- matrix_(c(0, 0), n, n)
>
> for(i in 1:n){   D[i, i] <- as.character(eigenVec_V_b[[i]]$eigval) }
>
> P <- matrix_(c(0, 0), 1, n)
>
> for(i in 1:n){   P[,i] <- as.character(eigenVec_V_b[[i]]$eigvec) }

To test whether the code is implemented correctly, simply run the `P %*% D %*% inv(P)` and it should return the same matrix as `M`

To get the square root of M, run `P %*% sqrt(D) %*% inv(P)`. The entries aren't simplified completely (even after applying the `simplify` function), so they won't match the original matrix, but the values appear correct once simplified by hand.